# Adding Packages, Version and Licenses to License Management App (LMA) in a Scratch Org / Sandbox

Tags: scratch-org, lma

I have installed the `License Management Application` (LMA) into a Scratch Org to enable us to build a data model that relates to the `License` and `Package` and `Package Version` objects.

- [ISVforce Guide: LMA Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_package_details.htm)

Says

> Don’t edit, delete, clone, or create packages, package versions, or licenses. These records are automatically created and contain important information for tracking the licenses and packages in the License Management App. They can’t be repopulated

The line `Don’t edit, delete, clone, or create packages, package versions, or licenses` seems quite clear, but how should I test against the `LMA` without test data?

Also, I am not 100% clear what `They can’t be repopulated.` means...

- [ISVforce Guide: Can I install the LMA in a non-production Salesforce org?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_faq_prod_org.htm)

Says:

> By default, the LMA is installed in your Partner Business Org, a production environment that includes the ISV tools needed to run your business. When the LMA is part of a production environment, you can fully integrate license management into your sales, billing, and marketing processes. Our most successful partners make use of the LMA in their production orgs.

> Additionally, some types of non-production environments, such as trial orgs, eventually expire. If this happens, your mission critical data becomes temporarily inaccessible. For these reasons, Salesforce strongly discourages moving the LMA to a non-production org.

The line `Salesforce strongly discourages moving the LMA to a non-production org.` is clearly telling not to do what I am doing, but I imagine they want to avoid people using the `LMA` to manage real licenses etc, rather than what I am trying to do.

I want to check that adding any records to the `LMA` objects in a scratch org isn't going to have long term \ global effects?

And that the data I enter is only going to be in the scratch org, and doesn't get registered anywhere on the global salesforce packaging infrastructure?

Is there an official Salesforce person who could unofficially help answer this?